# `flutter build appbundle`でbuildフォルダ内のファイルと重複しているというエラーが起こる

Tags: android, flutter, build

[Build and release an Android app - Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)に従い`flutter build appbundle`を実行したのですが、以下のようなエラーが起きます。

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [string/app_name] <app_root>\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml   [string/app_name] <app_root>\build\app\generated\res\resValues\release\values\gradleResValues.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

わかりやすいように一部<app_root>に置き換えてます。
読めばわかるようにbuildフォルダ以下にあるファイルの内容と自分で書いたコードの内容が重複してるとエラーが出てます。しかしbuildフォルダはビルド時に自動的に作られるものなのだからこのエラーはおかしいと思います（試しにbuildフォルダを削除しても同じエラーが起きます）。
どうすれば解決するでしょう？

Comment: clean cleanBuildCache しても同じですか？自動生成するための元ネタと、ご自分のコードに同じキー値を設定していたりしませんか？

Comment: `flutter clean cleanBuildCache`しても駄目でした。「自動生成するための元ネタと、ご自分のコードに同じキー値を設定」というのはどういうことでしょう？ 自分のコード以外にビルドするための元ネタが存在するということでしょうか？

Comment: `values\strings.xml`を消すとbuildは成功するようになりましたが、通常の実行(`flutter run`)はエラーが出るようになりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strings.xmlだけでなくbuild.gradleでもアプリ名を設定してたのが問題でした。

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Date Interval Logger"<-これを削除
```